# Why is my drop down menu not Working on HTML,CSS

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why my drop down menu that im trying to include is not appearing and i cant seem to find whats wrong, i saw that the only way for it to appear is to remove hidden but if i do that i doesnt look how i want it to, yet if i have the hidden when i hover over the servicios tab its not showing anything which i cannot find the reason on why it doesnt appear there

```css
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.hero{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.6)), url(bp.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;    
}
.nav_bar{
    display: flex;
    padding: 40px 120px;
}
.nav-logo img{
    width: 135px;
}
.nav_links{
    flex: 1;
}
.nav_links ul{
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav_links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 25px; 
}
.nav_links ul a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.nav_links ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.45s;
}
.nav_links ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}
.btn{
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 0;
    background: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav_links .btn{
    float: center;
}
.frase{
    margin: 100px 130px;
    color: #fff;
}
.frase h1{
    font-size: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.vertical_bar{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.icono_busqueda{
    height: 60%;
    width: 80px;
}
.icono_busqueda .fa{
    margin: 45px 23px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.iconos_sociales{
    height: 60%;
    width: 80px;
} 
.iconos_sociales .fa{
    margin: 45px 23px;
    display: block;
    color:black;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.iconos_sociales{
    height: 35%;
    width: 80px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 27%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.iconos_sociales .fa{
    margin: 15px 15px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sub_menu_ser
{
    display: none;
}
.nav_links ul li:hover .sub_menu_ser
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.nav_links ul li:hover .sub_menu_ser ul
{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.nav_links ul li:hover .sub_menu_ser li
{
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.nav_links ul li:hover .sub_menu_ser ul li a:hover
{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
 
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Animal Care</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hero">
        <div class="nav_bar">
        <div class="nav_logo">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </div>
            <div class="nav_links">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Sobre Nosotros</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Servicios</li></a>
                       <div class="sub_menu_ser">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Peluqueria</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Veterinario</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cirugia</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Limpieza</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    <a href="#"><li>Contacto</li></a>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn">Registrarse</button>
        </div>
        <div class="frase">
            <h1>Cuidando a Nuestros <br> Mas Queridos</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Explorar</button>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical_bar">
            <div class="icono_busqueda">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
            </div>  
            <div class="iconos_sociales">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to hide the element:

```
#element {
    display: none;
}
```

Code to show the element:

```
#element:hover {
    display: block;
}
```